# C# Windows Forms Таблица кодировки букв английского или русского алфавита

Tags: c#, winforms

**Предыстория:** На метку в форме(как в скриншоте Задание) должна выводится таблица с буквами и кодировкой. Все действие должны происходить в событии Form_Load и можно использовать метод Convert.ToChar.

**Проблема:** но это только для одного символа. Я не понимаю, каким образом мне вывести все буквы в Label(метку)

**Вопрос:** направьте меня на решение данного задания. С чего начать?

Задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица кодов ASCII:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Соберите весь нужный текст в одной строке, для переноса строк можно вставить `\n`, `StringBuilder` в помощь. Полученную строку в `Label.Text`. Ни чего сложного.

Comment: StringBuilder, конечно, мощная штука, но преподаватель просит выполнить, используя циклы и условия

Comment: и как это противоречит использованию `StringBuilder`? Он вообще-то нужен для эффективной (по памяти) работы со строками.

Comment: Просто получается, насколько я понял, мы еще не дошли до использования классов, таких как StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (byte b = 1; b < 255; b++)
{
    if (b < 65 || (b > 90 && b < 97) || (b > 122 && b < 192)) continue;
    if (b % 4 == 0) s += "\n";
    char[] ch = Encoding.GetEncoding(0).GetChars(new byte[] { b });
    label1.Text += ch[0].ToString() + " - " + b.ToString() + "\t";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Виталий за подсказку. Мне тут помогли, но до конца задачку так и не решил. Сделал вывод только символов верхнего регистра, а надо еще с нижним вывести на форму. Можете помочь?

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cols = 2;// количество колонок
            int beg = 65;// первый символ
            int end = 90;// последний символ
            int rows = (end - beg) / cols; // количество строк
            for (int i = 0; i <= (end - beg); i++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(50 * (i / rows), 
                    30 * (i % rows)), AutoSize = true,
                    Text = ((char)(i + beg)).ToString() + " - " + (i + beg).ToString() });
            }
        }

Comment: поправил, попробуйте так

Comment: Сейчас попробую, а можете подсказать как код, который я вставляю в комментарий отмечался как код?

Comment: @randomesis тильда **без шифта** на англ языке (апостроф) с двух сторон слова

Comment: Ок. Я запустил и проверил. Я добавил переход на новую строку, чтобы столбцом вывод был. Но сначала идет кодировка, а потом символ. Как это поменять? И для того, чтобы вывести только заглавные и строчные символы, допустим англ. яз. (65-90) и (97-122) надо еще 1 цикл добавлять или как-то по-другому можно?

Comment: @randomesis так?

Comment: Что-то многовато символов он вывел =) Я вместо табуляции \t сделал \n. 122 последний был. Надо еще вывести их как на скриншоте в 4 ряда по 16 символов вроде. Но это для русских их 64. А английских 52. Можно тогда русские вывести чтобы 4 ровных столбца получить по 16.

Comment: @randomesis поиграйтесь с логикой и вывидите. У вас уже все отображается. Осталось понять как их вывести в 4 ряда (в моеем коде есть предпосылки, но они сбились после условия) так что дорабатывать Вам.